# WinUI 3 ComboBox ItemsSource binding Dictionary<string, CustomClassObject> throws InvalidOperationException "Target type is not a projected type"

Tags: c#, dictionary, xaml, winui-3

#### Describe the bug

`ComboBox`'s `ItemsSource` binding with `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` throws an error when `TValue` is a class object.

I'm using WinUI 3 with C# for my project.

I looked at many other similar posts which discuss about `ComboBox`'s `ItemsSource` binding with `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` and I'm pretty sure I'm doing everything correctly.
I even tested the code by using a `Dictionary<string,int>` object to bind to the `ComboBox` and it works without any problem.

But only when I use a class object as `TValue`, it throws this error:

```text
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in WinRT.Runtime.dll
Target type is not a projected type: App1.Sample
```

And the debugger shows that the problem occurs at `obj.ItemsSource = value;` in:

```
public static void Set_Microsoft_UI_Xaml_Controls_ItemsControl_ItemsSource(global::Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemsControl obj, global::System.Object value, string targetNullValue)
{
    if (value == null && targetNullValue != null)
    {
        value = (global::System.Object) global::Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlBindingHelper.ConvertValue(typeof(global::System.Object), targetNullValue);
    }
    obj.ItemsSource = value;
}
...
```

I tried to find posts which discuss about this error but did not yield any solutions.

#### Steps to reproduce the bug

1. Create a new Blank App, Packaged (WinUI 3 in Desktop) in Visual Studio
2. Add following code accordingly:

`MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Window
    x:Class="App1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind Samples}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Key"
                  SelectedValuePath="Value"></ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

`MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace App1 {
    public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Samples.Add("skdn", new());
        }

        public Dictionary<string, Sample> Samples = new();

        public class Sample {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public Sample() {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. Run the app

#### Expected behavior

The app should run without errors.

Comment: Please share a [mcve] not the whole project. Or just post the related code.

Comment: I think I posted the related code with `SearchPage.xaml`, `SearchPage.xaml.cs` and `Tag.cs`. I'm pretty sure those are enough for reproducibility. What could be improved?

Comment: It seems an issue, I suggest you could post the thread to [Github Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues) for better help.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a few months since the issue was posted here and it might be only a similar problem, but I would like to share my recent experience.

I faced a problem in my WinUI 3 application with *CommunityToolkit.Mvvm* package. The error message was

> Source object type is not a projected type and does not inherit from a projected type.

I had a view model class and a data template that I was using to display the data from the view model.

After some searching and code-checking, I noticed a mismatch between the target type of my data template and the view model class.

So to illustrate the problem, my view model class was as follows.

```
namespace MyApplication.WinUI3Client.ViewModels;

public partial class FeedViewModel : ObservableRecipient
{
    [ObservableProperty] private Guid _id;
    // ... the rest of the class
}
```

However, my data template in XAML resembled the following.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FeedItemTemplate" x:DataType="viewModels:FeedsViewModel">
    <Grid>
        <!-- The content of the data template -->
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Notice the discrepancy between the name of the class `FeedViewModel` and the target type of the data template `x:DataType="viewModels:FeedsViewModel"` (Feed vs Feeds) which was actually the parent view model containing individual feeds. After correcting the mistype it all started working again.

So looking at your code, I suspect the problem is in the internal representation of the Dictionary as IEnumerable of key-value pairs. I would try changing your target model of items source to a custom implementation. It would encapsulate both the key of the sample in the dictionary and the sample itself in one class or something similar that would fit your needs.
When trying out the way you proposed to reproduce the problem I was getting a problem

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>
> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'ABI.System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2' threw an exception.

Maybe it's because it does not have a parameterless constructor. Not sure. It's quite deep to debug. However, I would avoid using 'mapping' types like `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` for items source and create a viable custom representation contained in an `ObservableCollection<T>`.